# Get the data from text file from lines 2 to 4

Tags: vb.net

I have a project that needs to get the data from lines 2 to 4

**Sample data**

```
1Type
2DELL LAPTOP
3HP   LAPTOP
4ASUS LAPTOP
1ACCESSORIES
2DELL  MOUSE
3HP    MOUSE
4ASUS  MOUSE
```

**My code**

```
Dim myStreamReader As New IO.StreamReader("C:\tmp\Parts.txt")
Dim myStreamWriter As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\tmp\GetData.txt")
Dim getdata As String
Dim nLineCtr As Integer
Dim strline As String = objStreamReader.ReadLine()

While Not strline Is Nothing
    nLineCtr = nLineCtr + 1
    strline = objStreamReader.ReadLine
    If nLineCtr = 2 Or nLineCtr = 3 Or nLineCtr = 4 Then
        getdata = Mid(strline, 2, 11)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(getdata)
    End If
End While

myStreamWriter.Close()
myStreamWriter.Dispose()
myStreamWriter = Nothing
myStreamReader.Close()
myStreamReader.Dispose()
myStreamReader = Nothing
```

The result I get is

```
4ASUS LAPTOP
4ASUS  MOUSE
```

But the results I require are:

```
2DELL LAPTOP
3HP   LAPTOP
4ASUS LAPTOP
2DELL  MOUSE
3HP    MOUSE
4ASUS  MOUSE
```

How should I change my code the get the results I require?

Answer (score 0):

On my phone so I'll make it simple:

No need to stream. Just use System.IO

```
Dim lines() As String = file.ReadAllLines
Dim output As String

For Each line In lines
    Dim index As Integer = Int32.TryParse(line(0))
     If (index > 1 And index < 5) Then
         Output += line & vbNewLine
     End If
Next
```

Then strip the last new line.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew, I put everything in a list and then set up to skip every 4th line. This should work for any size file as long as the pattern remains the same.

```
Sub Andrew()
        Dim lstData As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines("C:\MyFolder\Charles.txt").ToList
        Dim lstSelectedData As New List(Of String)
        Dim nLineCtr As Integer = 1
        Dim strLine As String = ""
        Dim SkipLine As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To lstData.Count - 1
            If SkipLine <> i Then
                lstSelectedData.Add(lstData(i))
            Else
                SkipLine += 4
            End If
        Next
        For Each s As String In lstSelectedData
            Debug.Print(s)
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a substring.

```
While Not strline Is Nothing
nLineCtr = nLineCtr + 1
strline = objStreamReader.ReadLine
If nLineCtr = 2 Or nLineCtr = 3 Or nLineCtr = 4 Then

    getdata = strline.Substring(0, 1)
    myStreamWriter.WriteLine(getdata)

    End If
End While
```